# Executing code when a branch is removed in Jenkins' multi branch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins that uses [multi branch project](https://jenkins.io/blog/2015/12/03/pipeline-as-code-with-multibranch-workflows-in-jenkins/). That is, when a new branch is created to repository, Jenkins automatically will automatically create a new job for the branch, and remove that job when the branch is removed.

Now, I'd like to run some code when the branch is removed, to clear testing environments that were created when the branch was created. It there a way to do this?

Comment: Feature request for this in Jenkins issue tracker - https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40606

Answer (score 2):

Not without writing plugin code I think. If you are interested, the relevant extension point would be `OrphanedItemStrategy` from the `cloudbees-folder` plugin.

Comment: Is this still the best option at this time? Does this mean that I have to fork the cloudbees-folder plugin, make the changes there, and the build and install on my own Jenkins? (or did the plugin change since 2016)

Comment: Clarification: I have a multibranch-pipeline project, and I would like to invoke custom code when a folder is deleted, so that I can remove the testing environment that I created for the branch when it was detected first.

Comment: people must have infinite resources ... :-D

Comment: Any solution exists in 2019?

Comment: @guyromb nope =/

Answer (score 2):

Nowdays there is [multibranch-action-triggers-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/multibranch-action-triggers-plugin). This seems have the functionality I asked for. Not tested though.

> This plugin enables building/triggering other jobs when a Pipeline job is created or deleted, or when a Run (also known as Build) is deleted by a Multi Branch Pipeline Job.